# Sharing Device Server Attribute with Related Asset Attribute

Tags: thingsboard

perhaps someone could assist me with this. I need to share a server attribute (specifically, the "active" attribute) from a device with its related asset. I want to ensure that the asset also has an attribute called "active," with its value mirroring that of the related device. It's worth noting that there's already a "Contains" type relationship established from the device to the asset.

In the rule chain, I attempted to add a 'Change Originator' node following the 'Save Attributes' and 'Save Server Attributes' nodes. However, when I enabled debug mode, I observed that attribute updates such as 'active,' 'lastActivityTime,' 'lastConnectTime,' etc., never passed through the 'Change Originator' node when I sent telemetry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for events' Activity event 'and' inactivation event 'in the rule chain